# Overload resolution for inherited functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, lambda, overloading

I want to have a struct that takes an arbitrary number of lambdas and serve as a central calling point for all their call operators.

If the call operator is invoked with an argument list that doesn't match any of the lambdas given on construction, a default call operator should be called.

I thought the following code would accomplish exactly this. The call operator for every lambda is "lifted" into the `Poc` class via `using`.

```
template <typename ...Lambdas>
struct Poc : Lambdas...
{
    using Lambdas::operator() ...; // Lift the lambda operators into the class

    template <typename ...Ts>
    auto operator() (Ts...)
    {
        std::cout << "general call" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Deduction guide
template <typename ...Ts>
Poc(Ts... ts)->Poc<Ts...>;

int main()
{
    auto l_int = [](int) {std::cout << "int" << std::endl; };

    Poc poc{l_int};
    poc(1);//calls the default operator. why?

    return 0;
}
```

When I don't have the default call operator in the struct, everything works as expected (with valid argument lists). If I add it to the struct (as in the code above), the default operator gets called everytime, no matter which arguments I call it with.

In my understanding, the lambda-call-operators and the structs (default) call-operator are present in the same scope. Therefore, they should all be looked at for the overload resolution. Since the lamdba-operator is more specific than the generic default operator, it should be chosen.

Apparently that is not the case. Why is that?

I tested on [Microsoft Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B), [Clang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (all in their latest versions).

Edit:

- MSVC 15.8.9
- GCC 9.0.0 (via [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/))
- Clang 8.0.0 (via [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/))

Comment: quite an interesting thing you have there. If you dont mind I will steal the idea (just to have some fun with it ;)

Comment: @YSC It's not CRTP, in CRTP, `derived` inherits from `base<derived>`.

Comment: @Walter Ho that's true. I let myself carried away by that code snippet. This is funny how C++ nerds as myself can become quite ecstatic with so little :)

Comment: Consider an edit: Replace _all in their latest versions_ with their actual versions, so people in the future have a good reference point.

Comment: @studog Good point, I added the versions. Since this concept seems to attract a bit of attention, I'm thinking of writing blog post about how we actually plan to use it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's simple when you spot it: your operator is not `const`-qualified, while [the lambda's one](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-4) is (unless you define the lambda as `mutable`). Hence, it is a better match for your non-const instance of `Poc`.

Just add the missing`const`:

```
auto operator() (Ts...) const
```

Comment: So in this case const qualification trumps template instantiation, and it will stamp out the template to not make `*this` `const`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, this constitutes an implicit conversion of `this` which ranks the non-template operator lower. Pardon me if I don't go spelunking through the overload resolution standardese and keep my "just qualify everything equally and all'll be good" stance ;)

Comment: [Just like non-member overload resolution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/266b0b6438be8315)